# Make a bootable USB on Kali Linux

Tags: command-line, usb, kali-linux, bootable

So I just got that new laptop which is DOS free and I'd like to install Windows and Ubuntu for gaming and work.
Problem is I don't have any other computer available for now and the only OS I have is Kali Linux on a bootable USB stick.
So I'd like to know if it's possible to make a bootable USB stick from Kali Linux and how!

I know UNETbootin however I don't know which distribution I should get or even the commands.
If I only need the iso file, please teach me the commands I need to use to make it work. (And which commands I should use to install unetbootin if possible)

What I have :

- The new laptop which doesn't have an OS --> dos free (only have access to bios).
- A bootable USB stick with Kali Linux on it.
- Another USB stick that I'd like to make bootable with Windows if possible (then I know how to do when I have Windows to get Ubuntu in addition).

Comment: Please clarify what you have and what you need. If the only computer you have is the new laptop, and you have Kali Linux on USB stick, that must already be a bootable USB stick, right? Recommendations of distributions are pretty much off-topic as everyone has a different opinion.

Comment: ...and what do you mean by "DOS free"? It's been a more than a decade since anything was bundled with anything that had anything to do with DOS...

Comment: It's DOS free because it costed 200$ less and I already have a windows key so I would like to download it from internet to install it.

Comment: You must be using DOS in some meaning that is not familiar to me. So you have a laptop without an OS, ok.

Comment: Have you looked at solutions provided with search? http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=bootable+usb+%09is%3Aanswer

Comment: Yes but i didn't find anything for kali linux

Comment: DOS --> distributed operating system (isn't it ? Maybe it's just me)

Comment: @zagrimsan do you know how to do it ? (You would save my life)

Comment: No, I don't have any experience on Kali Linux, and only once have I created a bootable USB stick on Linux. However, you only need a tool and to know if that tool requires an ISO image or something else to make a bootable USB drive, and just pick a tool that you can find from Kali (or can install from it's repository).

Comment: As for DOS, I go with [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS). Distributed OSes still seem more of a science project than a commodity, and don't commonly share the acronym (unless you're working with that part of computing science, possibly).

Answer (score 1):

Creating a bootable USB drive is the same on Kali as it is on Ubuntu or any other Linux distro. First, you must plug in your USB drive and figure out what drive is (/dev/sda, /dev/sdb, ect.). You could use a program like GParted or you could just use the command fdisk -l. Next make sure that your USB drive is not mounted by using the command

```
$ umount /dev/sdx
```

where /dev/sdx is your USB drive

After you know this, you can use the `dd` command to write the image to the drive.

```
$ dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=512k
```

Just be sure that you don't write to a partition of the drive (aka /dev/sdx1). This could result in corruption.